# How to find the universal sink of a directed graph with an adjacency-matrix representation

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

I'm working on an excercise (self-study):
"Show how to determine whether a directed graph G contains a universal link - a vertex with in-degree (V-1) (V is the number of vertices) and out-degree 0 in time O(V), given an adjacency matrix for G.
I have written the code here:

```
    int UniversalSink(const int *a, int N)
{
    int i,j,i1,j1,q;
    i=0;


    i=0;
    q=YES;
    j=-1;
    do
    {
    j++;
    if (j==N)
        break;

    while ( (*(a+i*MAX+j)) ==0 )
    {
        j++;
        if (j==N)
        {

        break;
        }
    }
    if (j==N)
        break;
    q= YES;

    for (; i<j; i++)
        if ( (*(a+i*MAX+j)) ==0 )
        {
           i=j,j=i-1;
           q= NO;
           break;
        }
    if (q==NO)
        continue;
    q=YES;

    /*
    for (i=0; i<=j; i++ )
        if (a[j][i] ==1 )
        {
        i=j;
        q=NO;
        ok=NO;
        trai = NO;
        break;

        }
    if (q==NO)
        continue;
    */
    q=YES;

    for (i1= j+1; i1<N; i1++)
        if ((*(a + i1*MAX +j)) ==0 )
        {
        i=i1, j=i-1;
        q=NO;
        break;

        }
    if (q==NO)
        continue;
    }
    while (j<N);

    {
    i1=i;
    for (j1=0; j1<N;j1++)
        if ( (*(a + i1*MAX +j1 ))  ==1 )
        return -1;
    j1=i;
    for (i1=0; i1<N;i1++)
    {
        if (i1==j1)
        continue;
        if ( (*(a + i1*MAX +j1))==0)
        return -1;
    }
    return i;

    }
```

It takes a N-N matrix and returns the position of the universal sink (0 to N-1 if it exists and -1 if it doesn't)
However I don't really know if it is O(V) or not, and in fact I'm not sure if it will always compute the desired result at all

(Feel free to comment on any other aspect of my code e.g. using too many breaks)

Comment: Please describe what your code does. The answer to this problem is very simple and shouldn't require this much effort. Here's a hint: Write an adjacency matrix (on a piece of paper) of a directed graph containing a universal sink, figure out what's special about it, and write code to detect that property. Also, use meaningful variable names. One-letter variable names are impossible to understand.

Comment: My bad. My solution works as follows: From (i,j) that i=j (initially i=j=0 ) go to the right until a[i][j] =1, then all the vertices from 0 to j-1 cannot be an universal sink. If vertex j satisfies, a[i][j] =1 from column i to j-1 we just check it if it doesn't set i=j. After that you go downward (incrementing i) to see if there is any 0 if there is, set j=i, repeat again. When j=N it has checked all of the matrix, we check again at column i and row i to see if it satisfies, if it does then return i, if it doesn't then there is no universal link.

Comment: There are really only 2 cases: `a[i][j] == 1`, in which case we increment `i`, and `a[i][j] == 0`, in which case we increment `j`. See **Problem 4** here: http://web.mst.edu/~ercal/253/SLIDES/PDF/Lec-22.pdf

Comment: The algorithm there seems to have the same idea as me. However I feel strange, when a[i][j] = 1 why do we have to increment i by just 1??? Because we already know that all vertices up to (j-1) cannot possibly be a universal sink, why don't we just set i=j (since for every step it is guaranteed that i<=j) , that way we would save some checkings for all those (i<j). P/s: Some miscellanous here, it says " If A[u][v]=0, then v cannot be a universal sink" but if u=v then this does not hold true

Comment: See Problem 2 here : http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cot5405fa09/assignments/solhw3.pdf

Comment: @beaker help me please

Comment: The reason they only increment `i` by 1 is to simplify the code into one loop. You'll get there eventually, and `O(2|V|)` is still `O(|V|)`. If you want to, you could probably do something like `i=max(i+1,j)`. They also state at the beginning of the question that `A[u][u] = 0`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following code:

```
int DetectSink(matrix G, int V) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < V && j < V)
        if (G[i][j])
             i = i + 1;
        else j = j + 1;
    if (i < V && IsSink(G, i)) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

If k is an universal sink, then  the k-th
row of the adjacency-matrix ( `G` ) will be
all 0s, and the k-th column will  be  all
1s (except `G[k][k] = 0`).

OBS: We can conclude that there is at most one sink.

If an univeral sink `k` exist in `G`, then eventually,
we get to position `(i = k, j)` or `(i, j = k)`.

```
            k
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   | 1 |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   | 1 |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
k | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   | 1 |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   | 1 |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

If we reach column  `k (j=k)` before row  `k (i=k)`,
our algorithm excecutes  the  **then**  block  until
`(i = k, j = k)`, then it executes  the **else** block
until `(i = k, j = V)`.
In other case, if k-th row is reached first than
k-th column, then the **else** block  excecutes  to
the end of while loop until `(i = k, j = V)`.

At the end we must check if `i` is an universal
sink, because we know if a sink exist it is `i`,
but we have not idea what our algorithm is going
to do if an universal sink is not in `G`.

The running time is `O(V)`, because in every step
we increment `i` or `j`, so at most `2V` such
operations occurrs. The `IsSink` part is `O(V)`.

There is a nice solution using Divide & Conquer:

In  this  solution  we  keep  a  set  of candidates
to universal sink and in every  step  we make pairs
of vertexs and discard one of two vertexs, in order
to  analize  one  half  of  the initial candidates.

Comment: I am not convinced that your algo really works. If we take the example above: What if the sink is on the last column and (0,1) = 1 and (1,1) = 0 and (0,2) = 0? It would still detect the middle column as sink but it isn't. And the real sink would not be detected. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @RichArt , create the full matrix and then execute the algorithm above.

Comment: Yes, now I am convinced:
If the algo encounters a 0 it goes right, if it encounters a 1 it goes down. So, if there is a universal sink `k`, then it has out-degree = 0. So, the k-th row has to have all 0's. This represents a "barrier" in direction down. Furthermore `k` has in-degree = |V| -1. So, the k-th column has to have all 1's except (k, k). This represent a "barrier" in direction right.
The last IF is needed because we didn't check if column `k` has also 1's below the 0-"barrier".