# What is a Theta(n) algorithm to find the node in a directed adjacency matrix with indegree(n-1) & outdegree(0)?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

If you have a directed graph represented as an n x n adjacency matrix, I need to find an algorithm such that it will output the node of indegree(n-1) and outdegree(0) if it exists; if it doesn't, I need it to output False. This needs to have a time complexity of Theta(n), and it must be a graph stored as an adjacency matrix due to the confines of this problem.

A proof that it returns the node if it exists would also be helpful.

Comment: Can there be elements greater than 1 in the adjacency matrix?

Comment: @Stef Yeah, I am assuming that there can be 1 element in the matrix, and a number of elements greater than 1.

Comment: If the adjacency matrix contains only zeroes and ones, then a node with indegree n-1 and outdegree 0 is called a **universal sink**. And that would make your question a duplicate, with an answer here: [How to find the universal sink of a directed graph with an adjacency-matrix representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29265072/3080723)

Comment: Precision: what is important here is not that there is no value larger than 1 in the matrix, but that the node you are looking for has incoming edges from every other node. But if the matrix has values larger than 1, then it is possible for a node to have indegree n-1 while not having incoming edges from every other node.

Comment: *"I am assuming that there can be 1 element in the matrix"*: I don't understand this phrase.

Comment: @trincot that nxn can be 1x1.

Comment: But that is not what Stef was asking about. Stef was asking about the *values* in the adjacency matrix. Are they all zeroes and ones, or can there be other numbers appearing in that matrix as well, indicating more than one edge exists between the same pair of vertices?

Comment: @trincot The instructions say that the node "has
received information from _all_ n − 1 other people and who has not given any data to anyone else" meaning what Stef is referring to about a node not having incoming edges from every other node not happening when the matrix has values larger than 1 cannot happen in this problem, meaning only one edge exists between the same pair of vertices.

Comment: @Stef what would a proof that this returns the right node kinda look like?

Comment: @JohnAdams the explanation in the answer is a good start. This comment also helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259365/how-to-find-the-universal-sink-of-a-directed-graph-with-an-adjacency-matrix-repr#comment80294332_29265072 If the id of the universal sink is k, then you need to prove that variables (i, j) will eventually reach values (i = k, j) or (i, j= k); since at every iteration of the loop, we have `if (...) i = i + 1; else j = j + 1;` this is guaranteed; then looking at the diagram in the answer explains why eventually we'll get to (i = k, j = n-1).

Comment: @Stef Makes sense. Thank you!!